# Flask send_file() equivalent in Django

Tags: python, django

do you know what is the Django equivalent command for the below Flask command:

```
return send_file("output_file.json")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you're look for `HttpResponse`, specifically [Telling the browser to treat the response as a file attachment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment).

So:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

then:

```
return HttpResponse(open("output_file.json"))
```

If you want to serve this as a downloadable attachment to the browser, you need to do this via the `Content-Disposition` header (which is what the `as_attachment` and `attachment_filename` arguments to `send_file` do in Flask):

```
response = HttpResponse(open("output_file.json), content_type="application/json")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="downloaded_file.json"'
return response
```